# Generating Google Chart on the fly with JSP

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, code-generation, google-visualization

I am using a Google Line Chart to graph values pulled from a database using JSP.  I currently have have it working.  The `data.addColumn` statements are generated from a database query when the page loads.

My problem is that I also want to have a couple of comboboxes that can be used to pick min and max values for the x-axis and then update the graph.  Currently the only way I can think to accomplish this is refresh the page with new get parameters.

I would prefer to somehow only refresh the chart itself without reloading the entire page.  Is this possible? Is there a way to overwrite the script tag and then reload the chart? Or is there some other way?

EDIT: I am having trouble figuring out how to pass the data from the database over to the loading page.  Here is my code:

**loader.html (page the holds the chart and date fields):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadChart()
        {
            var xmlhttp;            
            var minDate = document.getElementById('startDate').value;
            var maxDate = document.getElementById('endDate').value;

            if (!minDate)
                minDate = 'none';
            if (!maxDate)
                maxDate = 'none';

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                {
                    document.getElementById('lineChart').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "chart-loader.jsp?min=" + minDate + '&max=' + maxDate, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">

        <div id="lineChart"></div>

        <div id="startDateBox">
            <label for="startDate">Min Date:</label>
            <input id="startDate" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div id="endDateBox">
            <label for="endDate">Max Date:</label>
            <input id="endDate" type="text" />
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Update" id="updateBtn" onclick="loadChart()" />

    </div> <!-- End container -->
</body>
</html>
```

**chart-loader.jsp (supposed to get data and load the chart)**

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*, java.util.ArrayList" %>
<%      
    Connection conn;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://...", "user", "pass");
    }
    catch(SQLException e) 
    {
        out.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage() + "<br/>");
        while((e = e.getNextException()) != null)
            out.println(e.getMessage() + "<br/>");
        throw new UnavailableException(this, "Cannot connect with the specified database.");
    }

    String data = "";
    String minDate = (String)request.getParameter("min");
    String maxDate = (String)request.getParameter("max");
    try
    {
        ResultSet rs;
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        if (minDate.equals("none") || maxDate.equals("none")) // First load, use whole table
        {
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT ...");
        }
        // ... more possible queries

        ArrayList<String> ptVals = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> colDates = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (rs.next())
        {
            ptVals.add(rs.getString("avgvalue"));
            colDates.add(rs.getString("collectiondate"));
        }           
        // ptVals.size()
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            data += "\t\t\tdata.addRow(['" + colDates.get(i) + "'," + ptVals.get(i) + "]);\n";  

        // ... Use out.print to spit out script. 
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        data = "SQLException: " + e.getMessage() + "<br/>";
        while((e = e.getNextException()) != null)
            data += e.getMessage() + "<br/>";           
    }       
    finally
    {   // Clean up resources, close the connection.
        if(conn != null)
        {
            try { conn.close(); }
            catch (Exception ignored) {}
        }
    }
%>
```

**Original script to load the chart**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function drawVisualization() 
    {
        // Create and populate the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Temperature');
        data.addRow(["01/01/11", 70.2]);
        data.addRow(["01/02/11", 70.0]);
        data.addRow(["01/03/11", 69.8]);
        data.addRow(["01/04/11", 70.1]);
        // Create and draw the visualization.
        new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('lineChart')).
            draw(data, {backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                        width: 700, height: 400,
                        legend: 'none',
                        hAxis: {title: 'Dates', titleTextStyle: {color: 'black', fontSize: 12, fontName: 'Verdana, Arial'}},
                        vAxis: {title: 'Temperature', titleTextStyle: {color: 'black', fontSize: 12, fontName: 'Verdana, Arial'}},
                        chartArea: {left: 80, top: 20}
                    }
                );
    }

    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
</script>
```

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work with Google Visualization API.  Here's how:

I have an HTML page that has a container `div` for the graph. `<div id="lineChart"></div>`

Next I have two JavaScript functions in the HTML page.  The `getChartData()` function is an AJAX function that gets the date range from two input fields and sends them to a JSP page.  The JSP page uses the dates to query the database for records in that range, formats them as a JavaScript object, and sends it back to the HTML page using `out.print()`.

Once the HTML page receives the data, it uses `eval()` to set the received text as a JavaScript object. Finally, the data object is sent to the second JavaScript function, `loadChart()`, which uses the data to call the Google functions and load the chart into the `div`.

Note: using `eval()` to set the `responseText` to a JavaScript object is what really makes it all work.  This allows you to pass many pieces of data back.  You simply pull them out of the JS object once you're back in the HTML page. You may even pass several JS objects inside each other.

```
var paramsObj;
var dataObj;
eval('paramsObj = ' + xmlhttp.responseText + ";");
eval('dataObj = paramsObj.data;');
loadChart(dataObj, paramsObj.title, paramsObj.xLabel);
```

In this case I'm passing three parameters in one JS object. `paramsObj.data` is the chart data, which came as a nested object which is formatted according to the Google Visualization API. I had to use `eval()` again to set the nested JS object as a separate variable, or it doesn't pass to the `loadChart()` function correctly.  `paramsObj.title` and `paramsObj.xLabel` are simply strings.

Answer (score 1):

We do exactly that where I work (refresh a google chart I mean). What we do is have the page load without the chart, and just Ajax-load it into whatever container it needs to be in. Then, when you change anything on it, have the ajax re-load it, sending whatever parameters you need to to the JSP (which gets a new chart).

EDIT: In case that didn't make sense, the chart itself is actually on it's own JSP that gets injected into the page (and refreshed) independently.

So our process is this:

Render main page (charts are NOT rendered yet). On this page, we put in something like this:

`<div id="chartForData1"></div>`

`<script>Ajax_inject('chartForData1', 'pageThatGeneratesData1');</script>`

Where `Ajax_inject` is just our wrapper for an Ajax call that loads data into an element. Now, when the page is rendered on the user's computer, that `Ajax_inject` (and all the others) will execute, thereby loading into the relevant `div` the corresponding rendered JSP. Those JSP's sole purpose to take a couple parameters (or none and use defaults) and render us a nice and pretty google chart.

Does that make more sense?

Comment: Do you use an include statement to inject the JSP file?

Comment: @Ryan: No, what we do is instead of outputting the chart data directly into the main page with an include, we write out the Javascript to the page to do the Ajax call. The loaded chart/page has Javascript in it to listen for the changes and reload.

Comment: I don't think I'm quite following. When you say Ajax call are you referring to Google's `google.setOnLoadCallback()` or `google.load()`? Or are you talking about custom stuff?  Do you know of any examples?

Comment: @Ryan: No examples that I can share, but maybe my edited answer has a clearer explanation... (If it isn't changed hold on, I'm changing it now)

Comment: After tinkering with this, I have more questions. How does `Ajax_inject` load the chart? From what I can find, I can only return text from the JSP page to the loading page after I make the database query (assuming you are using `XMLHttpRequest`). Are you returning the `<script>` that creates the chart?  I'm added sample code to my original post. Thanks again for all your help so far.

Comment: @Ryan: Ah, you are doing it quite differently than we are. We are using the Google Chart Tools (http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/faq.html#whatis) and embedding the GC url into the `src` field of an `img` tag.